# How can I use C++11 grammar while compiling it with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, visual-studio-2019, dllexport

First of all, It's been 3 months since I started coding, so I might not know what I'm saying.

Feel free to correct me.

I have a question about using some API that is developed in C++11.

I am restricted to use only Visual Studio 2019.

The problem happens whenever I use std::string type data.

Because I'm using the API that is not opened I can only assume what the problem is.

When I declare a variable like this.

```
std::string* strCopy = new std::string(strOriginal);
```

It works, but when I code like this.

```
std::string strCopy = strOriginal;
```

or like this.

```
std::string strCopy(strOriginal);
```

Visual Studio don't even print the error log and just stop.

Some might say, "Then why don't you use the one that works", but the real problem is when I use std::vector, because while using vector I can't declare the std::string type data inside by using 'new' expression.

I was thinking if there is a way that I can build the code for only std::string type data with C++11 by using DLL or by defining something.

If anyone know how to solve this kind of problem or have dealt with similar problem please give me some advice.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your question contains no useful information about the problem. Nobody knows what this "closed API" is and how to use it correctly. There is nothing technically wrong per se with any of your variables. They may become wrong only in the context of a complete program.

Comment: I see that you need to put the function into the DLL, this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170) can help you.

Comment: `std::string` is part of the C++ standard library (which is part of the C++ standard). It's probably one of the best (and most precisely) documented APIs for C++. Whatever the guys at MS did - they probably tried to implement it as close as possible according to the standard. `std::string` isn't an exotic feature - it's probably one of the most used classes of the C++ standard library. If it doesn't work on your side I'm for 99.999 % sure that it isn't broken - you just used it in a wrong way.

Comment: Btw. C++ and DLL export has to be used with care. It works if everything is compiled with the same MSVC compiler (and the carefully chosen appropriate command line arguments). While other platforms define an ABI (application binary interface) which makes code independent of the compiler (version) to some degree - this didn't exist for MSVC for a long time. (I believe it's available now.) DLLs with C++ interface aren't universally exchangeable. A usual workaround are DLLs with a C interface for which compatibility between different compiler (versions) is much easier to achieve.

Comment: Btw.² A lot of the C++ standard library stuff is provided as `template`s. DLLs and C++ `template`s are a topic on its own. Using `template`s in the exported DLL interface is good for strange effects under certain conditions. Though, I cannot remember ever having had issues with `std::string` concerning this. The trouble I can remember was when I used templates (e.g. `std::vector`) in my own templates and intended to "export" them. (Actually, `template` is a blue-print of code i.e. it doesn't provide symbols which could be DLL-exported in the usual sense. I assume that's the problem at all.)

Comment: Could you please provide a sample to help everyone understand your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the API that is not opened".

This code works fine for me:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    std::string original = "ABCDEF";
    std::string strCopy = original;
    std::cout << strCopy << std::endl;
}
```

and when I run it, it prints "ABCDEF".
What happens when you compile that program?

Comment: What I meant by "the API that is not opend" was  the function I had to use is released as DLL so I can't figure out what is the problem.
And the problem I'm facing is not when it runs by itself but when I try to build while using the function I just mention above nothing happens